# Kusto query multiple resources by type, not by name

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitoring

I have written a simple query that shows exceptions from multiple instances of Application Insights:

```
app('app_insights_name_1').exceptions
| more unions here
| union app('app_insights_name_n').exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize count() by problemId, appName
| sort by count_ desc
```

I have also managed to write a query that finds all App Insights instances I would like the 1st query to run against:

```
resources
| where type in ~('microsoft.insights/components', 'microsoft.insights')
| where(resourceGroup in ~('dev', 'test'))
```

I don't think it is possible to combine both queries, but I wonder if it's possible to interrogate a union of Exceptions tables (or Trace or any other) of all instances for a given type in one or more resource groups?

Conceptually I wish for something similar to the query below:

```
resources
| where type in ~('microsoft.insights/components', 'microsoft.insights')
| where(resourceGroup in ~('dev', 'test'))
| MAGIC_HERE : get union of all exception tables from above 
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize count() by problemId, appName
| sort by count_ desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the below [tech community blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/azure-resource-graph-integration/m-p/1497499) you can integrate both log analytics & Azure resource graph using workbooks.

The [app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/app-expression) expression is used in an Azure Monitor query to retrieve data from a specific Application Insights app in the same resource group, another resource group, or another subscription. This is useful to include application data in an Azure Monitor log query and to query data across multiple applications in an Application Insights query.

Resources is a one of the table in resource graph explorer service in Azure that is designed to extend Azure Resource Management by providing efficient and performant resource exploration with the ability to query at scale across a given set of subscriptions so that you can effectively govern your environment. These queries provide the following features:

- Ability to query resources with complex filtering, grouping, and sorting by resource properties.
- Ability to iteratively explore resources based on governance requirements.
- Ability to assess the impact of applying policies in a vast cloud environment.
- Ability to  [detail changes made to resource properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes)  (preview).

Here is the reference [git hub](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/1ddc38529f498c209fb3fe21795f607d4cd232b7/Documentation/DataSources/DataSources.md#merge-data-from-different-sources) to create a application insights work books.